# Optimizations needed for USACO arithmetic progression problem

Tags: python

The problem statement:

*An arithmetic progression is a sequence of the form a, a+b, a+2b, ..., a+nb where n=0, 1, 2, 3, ... . For this problem, a is a non-negative integer and b is a positive integer.*

*Write a program that finds all arithmetic progressions of length n in the set S of bisquares. The set of bisquares is defined as the set of all integers of the form p2 + q2 (where p and q are non-negative integers).*

*The two lines of input are n and m, which are the length of each sequence, and the upper bound to limit the search of the bi squares respectively.*

My code solves the problem correctly, however it is too slow for the 5 second time constraint. Is there any way to further optimize my code?

```
import heapq

with open('ariprog.in', 'r') as fin, open('ariprog.out', 'w') as fout:
    length = int(fin.readline().strip())
    pqMax = int(fin.readline().strip())

    def isValid(start, diff):
        for i in range(1,length):
            if start + (diff*i) not in bisquares:
                return False
        return True

    bisquares = set()
    for p in range(pqMax+1):
        for q in range(pqMax+1):
            bisquares.add(p**2 + q**2)

    maxBS = max(bisquares) # do the calculation here so we only have to do it once

    res=[]
    for start in bisquares:
        for diff in range(1, (maxBS-start)//(length-1)+1):
            if start + (diff*(length-1)) > maxBS:
                break
            if isValid(start, diff):
                heapq.heappush(res, (diff, start)) # diff goes first in the tuple so it sorts by smallest diff first
    
    if res: # if res is non-empty
        while res:
            diff, start = heapq.heappop(res)
            fout.write(f"{start} {diff}\n")
    else:
        fout.write("NONE\n")
```

Comment: You are almost certainly being expected to find a better algorithm, rather than doing surface-level optimization.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Please edit your question to include sample input and expected output to allow testing of solutions, also you are expected to include an [mre] consisting of the least code necessary to reproduce your problem.  The code you have provided falls short of this expectation.

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).